# Cant send a value to another page in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Apologies if this is rudimentary, but I am not able to do a fairly simple task. I have a page where I have data rendered from an API into the cards like divisions. Ex:

```
<div class="card bg-light mb-3 offset-md-4" style={{ width: "30rem" }}>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">
      {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.name : ""}
    </h5>
    <p class="card-text">{post.emailAddress}</p>
    <p class="card-text">
      {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.phone : ""}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>;
```

For each data item, there is a card displayed on screen. I am trying to find a way to click one of these cards and show the data on Another page where I can Edit/ Delete the selected card's data, but I have not been able to succeed in doing so. Below is my full code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { URL } from "../Data/Env";

export default class UserPanel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser();
  }
  async getUser() {
    let url = URL.concat("authors");
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        if (response.data.statusCode == 200) {
          this.setState({ post: response.data.data });
        } else if (response.data.statusCode == 400) {
          console.log("User detail retrieving failed !!");
        } else {
          console.log("User detail unknown error !!");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  }
  showUser(post) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link
          to={{ pathname: "/UserDetail", state: [{ userId: post.userId }] }}
        >
          <div
            class="card bg-light mb-3 offset-md-4"
            style={{ width: "30rem" }}
          >
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">
                {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.name : ""}
              </h5>
              <p class="card-text">{post.emailAddress}</p>
              <p class="card-text">
                {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.phone : ""}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { post } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
          <div className="row col-md-12">
            <div className="offset-md-4">
              {" "}
              <h3>All Users</h3>{" "}
            </div>
            <div>
              <Link to={"/SignUp"}>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-success"
                  style={{ marginLeft: "146px", width: "234px" }}
                >
                  {" "}
                  Add User
                </button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div> {post.map(this.showUser)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you create separate child components instead of having everything inside the main component ?

Comment: Well, I am fairly new so still learning a bit of tips and tricks. Will certainly do so. How would creating a child component help with this particular problem. Can you please elaborate? @KavinduVIndika

Comment: So what you're trying to do is have all the user details cards in main page and once you click one of them, it should route to `/userDetail` page where it shows the selected user details right ? And still I don't understand what **Add User** button does ? It links to `/SignUp` page but from there, what are you trying to achieve ? Please, correct me if I'm wrong about any of the details I mentioned.

Comment: Add user button is a different functionality. We are not concerned with that. It just adds new users. We are only concerned with /userDetail page and main page (the page for which I have provided the code). You are correct about rest of the things @KavinduVIndika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `<Link>` outside `<Router>`. First you need to create the routes then you can use `<Link>` to navigate to the relevant page. It's better to have separate components relevant to each route. Refer this link for basic routing examples from react-router: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

For the OP's scenario, it is essential to have separate `Users` and `UserDetail` components, in which `Users` component shows all the users details and `UserDetail` component shows selected user details. `UserPanel` main component will be used to contain the routes of the application such as **/UserDetail**, **/SignUp**.

Following implementation can be used as a supprotive material for OP's scenario. In this case, data fetching from api has been mocked for the easiness of understanding.

**UserPanel.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import UserDetail from "./UserDetail";
import Users from "./Users";

export default class UserPanel extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <br />
          <br />
          <div>
            <div className="row col-md-12">
              <div className="offset-md-4">
                {" "}
                <h3>All Users</h3>{" "}
              </div>
              <div>
                <Link to={"/SignUp"}>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-success"
                    style={{ marginLeft: "146px", width: "234px" }}
                  >
                    Add User
                  </button>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
          </div>

          <Route exact path="/" component={Users} />
          <Route exact path="/UserDetail" component={UserDetail} />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Users.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const users = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    userDetails: { name: "john", phone: "111232" },
    emailAddress: "john@gmail.com",
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    userDetails: { name: "kamal", phone: "2222" },
    emailAddress: "kamal@gmail.com",
  },
];

export default class Users extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser();
  }
  async getUser() {
    await Promise.resolve(users).then((data) => this.setState({ posts: data }));
    /*
    mocked data fetching needs to be replaced with actual api invokation
    */
  }
  showUser(post) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="card bg-light mb-3 offset-md-4" style={{ width: "30rem" }}>
          <div class="card-body">
            <Link to={{ pathname: "/UserDetail", state: { post } }}>
              <h5 class="card-title">
                {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.name : ""}
              </h5>
            </Link>
            <p class="card-text">{post.emailAddress}</p>
            <p class="card-text">
              {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.phone : ""}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    return <div> {posts.map(this.showUser)}</div>;
  }
}
```

**UserDetail.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const UserDetail = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { post } = location.state;

  return (
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3 offset-md-4" style={{ width: "30rem" }}>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.name : ""}
        </h5>
        <p class="card-text">{post.emailAddress}</p>
        <p class="card-text">
          {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.phone : ""}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserDetail;
```

Following are the application views for the relevant routes.

**Route: /**

[image]

**Route: /UserDetail**

[image]

In above implementation, each card's title (user name) has been linked to the **/UserDetail** route which shows user details. **/SignUp** route doesn't contain a component, but it can be routed to a particular child component as similar to `Users` and `UserDetail` components.

`useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom` is used to get the location object relevant to the current URL. From it, **location state** can be extracted.

**Suggestions**

1. Since data fetched from api is an array of objects, keep it stored as **posts** instead of **post**. Be careful about variable naming.
2. Avoid using functions such as `showUser(post)` to introduce JSX elements into render method. Direclty introduce it into the component as follows.

```
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <div>
            <div
              class="card bg-light mb-3 offset-md-4"
              style={{ width: "30rem" }}
            >
              <div class="card-body">
                <Link to={{ pathname: "/UserDetail", state: { post } }}>
                  <h5 class="card-title">
                    {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.name : ""}
                  </h5>
                </Link>
                <p class="card-text">{post.emailAddress}</p>
                <p class="card-text">
                  {post.userDetails != undefined ? post.userDetails.phone : ""}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
```

3. Create react components in a reusable format. (Even I have duplicated the card component details in `Users` and `UserDetail` component. It's better to have separate child component as `CardDetails` to reuse it)

Comment: @Aveneet Singh, please kindly accept the answer and upvote if it does supportive of solving your issue

Comment: please upvote the question if you liked it